# linker command failed with exit code 1 when importing header files

Tags: objective-c

Im trying to import the file MobileDevice.h to 2 .m files in my project but im getting linker command failed with exit code 1 when i try it. Ive looked around for a while but found no solution. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD3em.jpg)

Comment: You should add mode detailed description what you did and the error you get

Comment: The linker is unrelated to header files; it's the pre-processor that handles include files.  You need to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

Select your target project:Build settings->Linking->Other Linker Flags Add:$(inherited)